# Focus next focusable element after dropdown selection in Vue 3

Tags: vuejs3, focus, dropdown, primevue

I have a Vue 3 invoicing app using composition api.

In the invoice table I have a filterable dropdown for product selection.

Here is the part of the table code,

```html
<tr v-for="(item, index) in items">
  <td data-label="No" class="text-center">{{ index + 1 }}</td>
  <td data-label="Item">
    <Dropdown
      v-model="item.product"
      :options="products"
      :disabled="item.disabled"
      option-label="product_name"
      :filter="true"
      @change="onProductChange(index, $event)"
    />
  </td>
  <td data-label="Quantity">
    <InputNumber
      v-model="item.quantity"
      class="input-text-right"
      mode="decimal"
      :min-fraction-digits="2"
      :max-fraction-digits="2"
    />
  </td>
</tr>
```

I have to make this invoice table completely keyboard accessible without the need to use a mouse
Everything works fine until a select a product in the dropdown. Once I select a product, the focus should go to quantity input automatically. Now it goes back to the very first focusable element on the page, which is the nav menu.

I tried emit to trigger tab press programatically and @blur to focus the next item. Nothing seems to be working.
I'm using PrimeVue components. Checked the docs. Nothing helpful there as well.

Could anyone help me please? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

add a ref to the quantity input, then in your `onProductChange` method you can focus that input

```html
<InputNumber
  ref="qtyInput"
  v-model="item.quantity"
  class="input-text-right"
  mode="decimal"
  :min-fraction-digits="2"
  :max-fraction-digits="2"
/>
```

`this.$refs.qtyInput` will be an array of all inputs with that matching ref created by the `v-for` but since you already pass in the index you can use that to select the correct one and focus it.

```js
onProductChange(index, event) {
  this.$refs.qtyInput[index].focus();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm using composition api.

Comment: I added `const qtyInput = ref(null)` in the setup. And tried to focus with `tyInput.value[index].focus()`. I got the error '_qtyInput.value is null_'.
Then I tried  `const qtyInput = ref({})` in the setup. This time the error was '_qtyInput.value[index] is undefined_'.